# C# htmlAgilityPack can't select nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to get the data from http://isin.twse.com.tw/isin/C_public.jsp?strMode=2
I used chrome extension **Xpath Helper** or **chrome developer mode** both I can get the nodes that I want by using `//tr[position()>2]/td[1]`

but when I used in my code

```
string url = "http://isin.twse.com.tw/isin/C_public.jsp?strMode=2";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc = web.Load(url);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[position()>2]/td[1]");
```

the node always null, what may cause this problem?
Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Your code works for me (13242 nodes).

Comment: But I can’t make it work in my code. That’s weird.

Comment: Also works for me (13314 nodes)